# magento $this->getCurrencies() can't work?

Tags: magento

i put the code in my theme header.phtml

`echo $this->getCurrencyCount() and $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()` both of them are no  any output. but i have set 4 currencies for the site.

but in the same file, `$this->getWelcome()` have the right output.why?

when i `echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();` in the file ,it has a value. thank you.
if i want to output the currency switcher. how do i do?

Answer (score 2):

These function are from the `Mage_Directory_Block_Currency` model, not the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` one.

You might look at the `directory/currency.phtml` file to handle this kind of task

IF you want to determine the best position in the page thanks to the header.phtml file, just define this block as a child of the header one.

In your theme layouts, in directory.xml, in the `<default>` area add this :

```
<reference name="header">
         <block type="directory/currency" name="header_currency" before="catalog.leftnav" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Then in the header.phtml file just add `echo $this->getChildHtml('currency');` where you need it to show.
If you just need these variables without showing the currency block use in your header.phtml this code

```
$currency_block = new Mage_Directory_Block_Currency;
$currency_block->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

The last part is provided as is and is untested.

Comment: if i want to use in the Page/Html/Header how do i do? thank you